# TempData not working after Session.Abandon()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, tempdata

I take some values to tempdata after Session.Abandon()

```
Session.Clear();
Session.RemoveAll();
Session.Abandon();
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
TempData["ClientCode"] = "democ";
return RedirectToAction("logoutmessage", "Account", new { cid = clientcode });
```

and in the view `logoutmessage.cshtml`

```
var urls = @Html.Raw(TempData["ClientCode"]);
```

But what I get in the urls is `null`.

What would be the probable reason.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @Jermy Yes my code worked, but Im not sure is that a solution. I placed the tempdata before session.abandon

Comment: Thank you for replying!

Comment: @Jermy post here if you get a better solution.